# Rename image file by post title

Tags: images

Best regards, I want to change the name of the automatic image with the title of the post.

For example, I have the image called 1231231252345.jpg and Title of the article is "Article for a test", I want to change the name of the image in "article-for-a-test.jpg"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the filter: [`wp_handle_upload_prefilter`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_handle_upload_prefilter).

## From the Codex:

> The single parameter, `$file`, represent a single element of the `$_FILES`
>   array. The `wp_handle_upload_prefilter` provides you with an opportunity
>   to examine or alter the filename before the file is moved to its final
>   location.

## Example code from the Codex:

```
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'custom_upload_filter' );

function custom_upload_filter( $file ){
    $file['name'] = 'wordpress-is-awesome-' . $file['name'];
    return $file;
}
```

### How to use this hook

```
add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'custom_upload_filter' );
function custom_upload_filter( $file ) {
    if ( ! isset( $_REQUEST['post_id'] ) ) {
        return $file;
    }
    $id           = intval( $_REQUEST['post_id'] );
    $parent_post  = get_post( $id );
    $post_name    = sanitize_title( $parent_post->post_title );
    $file['name'] = $post_name . '-' . $file['name'];
    return $file;
}
```

Comment: No, what I need is to rename the image name by the post name.. not to "wordpress-is-awesome-"..

Comment: That's just an example from the codex of the hook you need to use. I've updated my answer with a practical use of that hook.

Comment: I did this already but still not working. It keeps the image name. It doesn't take the post name

Comment: That's on you, mate. It works for me.

Comment: Actually it's working, the problem is that it keeps the old name after the post title. Example. Post title - "1234", and the image is 1234-1234-old-image-name.jpg

Comment: You really need to look at the code and understand what's going. You're on your own now.

Answer (score 0):

Found this article but unable to put it on place:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-auto-rename-based-on-current-post-title-a-media-defined-as-featured-image/